# Ansible read files line by line and delete lines on condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, file-manipulation

Am trying to read a file line by line and delete the line if certain conditions are met

sample input file:
**abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036

defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037

ghij Fri Jun 17 06:15:06 EDT 2022**

Expected output file:
**abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036

defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037**

The logic needed is read the file line by line and read the year at the last field. If it's less than 2023 then delete that line in the file. if greater than 2023 keep the line. in this example, the last line should be deleted , since the year 2022 is lesser than 2023.

sample code:

```
- name: read file   
  set_fact:
    root_certificate_content: "{{ lookup('file', /home/user/cert_cleanup/{{ output_file }}) }}"
  
- name: display   debug:
  year: "{{ root_certificate_content.split('\n') [-1]}}" 

- name: remove line
  << delete that line >>
  when:
   - year.value < 2023
```

I tried multiple options, nothing see to work. Error in 1st step itself

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036
defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037
ghij Fri Jun 17 06:15:06 EDT 2022
```

Get the content of the file

```yaml
  content: "{{ lookup('file', output_file) }}"
```

Split lines, create a list of the years, and create a dictionary from the years and lines

```yaml
  lines: "{{ content.splitlines()|map('split') }}"
  years: "{{ lines|map('last')|map('int') }}"
  lines_year: "{{ dict(years|zip(lines)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lines_year:
    2022: [ghij, Fri, Jun, '17', '06:15:06', EDT, '2022']
    2036: [abcd, Sat, Oct, '25', '04:30:35', EDT, '2036']
    2037: [defg, Tue, Dec, '01', '18:59:59', EST, '2037']
```

Reject the lines older than 2023 and join the lines

```yaml
  lines_2023: "{{ lines_year|dict2items|
                  rejectattr('key', 'lt', 2023)|
                  map(attribute='value')|map('join', ' ') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lines_2023:
  - abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036
  - defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037
```

Write the file

```yaml
     - copy:
         dest: "{{ output_file }}"
         content: |
           {% for line in lines_2023 %}
           {{ line }}
           {% endfor %}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    lines: "{{ content.splitlines()|map('split') }}"
    years: "{{ lines|map('last')|map('int') }}"
    lines_year: "{{ dict(years|zip(lines)) }}"
    lines_2023: "{{ lines_year|dict2items|
                    rejectattr('key', 'lt', 2023)|
                    map(attribute='value')|map('join', ' ') }}"

  tasks:

     - set_fact:
         content: "{{ lookup('file', output_file) }}"
       run_once: true

     - debug:
         var: lines_year|to_yaml
     - debug:
         var: lines_2023

     - copy:
         dest: "{{ output_file }}"
         content: |
           {% for line in lines_2023 %}
           {{ line }}
           {% endfor %}
       run_once: true
       delegate_to: localhost
```

gives running with options *--check --diff*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e output_file=/tmp/test.txt pb.yml -CD

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  lines_year|to_yaml: |-
    2022: [ghij, Fri, Jun, '17', '06:15:06', EDT, '2022']
    2036: [abcd, Sat, Oct, '25', '04:30:35', EDT, '2036']
    2037: [defg, Tue, Dec, '01', '18:59:59', EST, '2037']

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  lines_2023:
  - abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036
  - defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037

TASK [copy] ***********************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/test.txt
+++ after: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-16289938umqjl9j/tmpbav5odkq
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 abcd Sat Oct 25 04:30:35 EDT 2036
 defg Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037
-ghij Fri Jun 17 06:15:06 EDT 2022

changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Notes:

- The *lookup* plugins always execute on the localhost
- Read and write the file once. Set *`run_once: true`*
- Write the file back to localhost. Set *`delegate_to: localhost`*

Comment: Thanks for the code Vladimir . Am not able to rad the file with lookup. It always says  ```Unable to find
'//home/use/output_file' in expected paths ``` .  I have provided full 777 permissions to that file.